# Hyperref not playing nice with defined commands?

Tags: hyperref, italic

I want to use the hyperref package, for the purposes of hyperlinking citations and figures within my document. However when I just add hyperref to my preamble something strange happens.

I have a few self-defined commands that I use, such as this definition for italics:

```
\let\i\textit
```

However, hyperref for some reason doesn't play nice with this definition. All of my italics disappear and the italic command turns into what looks like a miniature numeral 1.

Would anyone know how to iron this out?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's a *very* bad idea to redefine `\i` that way.

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce the problem with

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\i\textit
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\i{xyz}

\end{document}
```

This happens because `hyperref` restores the definition of `\i` to produce the “dotless i” (what you mistake for a small numeral 1).

However, postponing the redefinition is not a good idea either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\i\textit

\begin{document}

\i{xyz}

naïve

\end{document}
```

will produce some mysterious errors:

```
! You can't use a prefix with `\aftergroup'.
<to be read again> 
                   \aftergroup 
l.10 naï
         ve
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \accent@spacefactor 
l.10 naï
         ve
? 
! Bad space factor (0).
<to be read again> 
                   \accent@spacefactor 
l.10 naï
         ve
?
```

Never use `\let` if you don't know what you're doing. Avoid redefining commands you don't know about and, in general, all commands that are related to outputting glyphs, such as `\i`.

Comment: Thank you! Incidentally, I have tried some different methods for redefining, for instance using `\newcommand`, and this also replicates the same problem. Is there something especially wrong with using `\let` in this context? Would there be a problem with redefining a different command, like `\it`?